# NoMethodError: undefined method `foreign_key' for ActiveSupport::Inflector:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.3

I have two models:
User and Account

user.rb:

```js
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
end
```

account.rb:

```js
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Migrations:

create_users:

```js
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

create_accounts:

```js
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.integer :number
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb:

```js
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160808203550) do

  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "number"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "accounts", ["user_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

In rails console I have:

User.first:

```js
User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Alisson", created_at: "2016-08-08 20:36:09", updated_at: "2016-08-08 20:36:09">
irb(main):002:0>
```

Account.first:

```js
Account.first
  Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Account id: 1, number: 124212, user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-08 20:36:27", updated_at: "2016-08-08 20:36:27">
irb(main):003:0>
```

Account.first.user:

```js
Account.first.user
  Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  ORDER BY "accounts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Alisson", created_at: "2016-08-08 20:36:09", updated_at: "2016-08-08 20:36:09">
```

But when a try get User's accounts I got and error:
User.first.accounts:

```js
User.first.accounts
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `foreign_key' for ActiveSupport::Inflector:Module
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:215:in `foreign_key'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:572:in `derive_foreign_key'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:330:in `foreign_key'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:163:in `join_keys'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:99:in `last_chain_scope'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:139:in `add_constraints'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:39:in `scope'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:5:in `scope'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:97:in `association_scope'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:423:in `scope'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:37:in `initialize'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `new'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `create'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `reader'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `accounts'
... 11 levels...
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from /home/alisson/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: what else you have in `Account` model?

Comment: I just have the association belongs_to :user in account.rb model and in account's table I have account's number and reference for user.